# Power BI: How to dynamically change currency

Tags: powerbi, dax

We have requirement to allow user to choose which currency he wants to see in the dashboard, like below example:

[image]

By default, it's `GBP`, if user changes to `USD`, we need to show the spend by USD. Under the hood we already have table `InvoiceDetail` which contains columns doing currency conversion beforehand:

```
SpendInGBP
SpendInUSD
SpendInEUR
```

I am not sure how I can map when user chooses different currency using ChicletSlicer to different Columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a table containing all formats available to apply this can be achieved.

I've created these tables as example:

```
MyTable
```

[image]

```
CurrencyFormat
```

[image]

In the `MyTable` table I've created two measures called `Format` and `Total Sales`.

```
Format = LASTNONBLANK ( CurrencyFormat[Format], 1 )
```

`Total Sales = Total Sales = FORMAT(SUM(MyTable[Sales]),[Format])`

Note `Total Sales` measures uses the `[Format]` measure to get the selected format from the slicer.

Adding the ChicletSlicer and setting `FormatName` column from `CurrencyFormat` table in `Category` pane, you should get the expected result.

[image]

Also note the formats I've used can vary from what you need, so you have to add some changes to the format strings, do a quick read of the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee634206(v=sql.105).aspx) about it.

```
    Format            Region
$#,##0;($#,##0)     SpendInUSD
£#,##0;(£#,##0)     SpendInGBP
€#,##0;(€#,##0)     SpendInEUR
```

**UPDATE:** OP wants to get the sum of the right column based on the slicer.

Fortunately your table has a column for every currency, as you found with my proposal to map the slicer value to your measure, this is the final expression:

```
Spend =
IF (
    LASTNONBLANK ( 'Currency'[Code], 1 ) = "GBP",
    SUM ( Invoice[SpendGBP] ),
    IF (
        LASTNONBLANK ( 'Currency'[Code], 1 ) = "USD",
        SUM ( Invoice[SpendUSD] ),
        SUM ( Invoice[SpendEUR] )
    )
)
```

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, my point is getting the right value for spend based on currency but you gave me an idea how to use LASTNONBLANK, my measure: `Spend = IF(LASTNONBLANK('Currency'[Code], 1) = "GBP", SUM(Invoice[SpendGBP]), IF(LASTNONBLANK('Currency'[Code], 1) = "USD", SUM(Invoice[SpendUSD]), SUM(Invoice[SpendEUR])))`, please update your answer then I can mark it.

Comment: @CuongLe, done. I Hope I have helped you with my answer.

Comment: Sure, your answer helped me alot ;)